Unable to connect my Dockerised Kotlin Spring Application and Postgres
I tried connecting my docker services, that is a Kotlin based SpringBootApplication with Postgres. I get a error saying password authentication failed for user "postgres" and
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256" when I try running docker-compose file the docker-compose up --build.
Error
docker-compose
I tried looking into solutions online, but wasn't able to figure out.
env_file:
SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=root
SPRING_DATASOURCE_DBNAME=postgres
SPRING_DATASOURCE_DB_PORT=5432
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=r2dbc:postgresql://db:5432/postgres

POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root
POSTGRES_DB=postgres

docker-compose:
version: "3"
services:
  application:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - portal

  db:
    image: postgres:14.7-alpine
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: root
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - portal
volumes:
  postgres_data:
networks:
  portal:

